# Create a C++ template class which can work like a Vector of Vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, vector

This is a Group class, similar to a Vector.  I can create a Vector of Groups and that works fine.  I'm having difficulty creating a Groups of Groups.  This code compiles and runs but the Group of Groups is not behaving in the same way to a Vector of Groups - see the output. I feel that I'm missing a special constructor in Group which handles templated types?  Perhaps it's something else - any pointers gratefully received.

```
#include <vector>

template <class T>
class Group
{
  private:
    T *data;
    int current_size;
    int max_size;

  private:
    void expand();

  public:
    Group();
    Group(int size);
    ~Group();

    T operator[](int index) const;
    int count() const;
    int add_item(const T new_item);
};

template <class T>
Group<T>::Group()
{
    data = NULL;
    max_size = 0;
    current_size = 0;
}

template <class T>
Group<T>::Group(int size)
{
    if (size < 2)
        size = 2;
    data = new T[size];
    max_size = size;
    current_size = 0;
}

template <class T>
Group<T>::~Group()
{
    if (data != NULL)
        delete[] data;
    current_size = 0;
    max_size = 0;
}

template <class T>
void Group<T>::expand()
{
    if (data == NULL)
    {
        current_size = 0;
        max_size = 2;
        data = new T[2];
    }
    else
    {
        //      printf("expanding %x from %d to %d\n", this, current_size, current_size*2);

        T *tempArray = new T[max_size * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < max_size; i++)
        {
            tempArray[i] = data[i];
        }

        delete[] data;
        data = tempArray;
        max_size = max_size * 2;
    }
}

template <class T>
int Group<T>::add_item(const T new_item)
{
    // expand the array if necessary
    while (current_size >= (max_size))
        expand();

    // add_item the new thing
    data[current_size] = new_item;
    current_size++;
    return (current_size);
}

template <class T>
inline T Group<T>::operator[](int index) const
{
    return data[index];
}

template <class T>
inline int Group<T>::count() const
{
    return current_size;
}

int main()
{
    // Vector of Groups works fine

    int numgroups = 3; // just 3 groups for testing

    // a vector of Groups
    std::vector<Group<int>> setofgroups(numgroups);

    printf("setofgroups count=%d\n", setofgroups.size());

    // some test data
    // 4 items in first group
    setofgroups[0].add_item(6);
    setofgroups[0].add_item(9);
    setofgroups[0].add_item(15);
    setofgroups[0].add_item(18);

    // one item in second
    setofgroups[1].add_item(7);

    // two items in third
    setofgroups[2].add_item(8);
    setofgroups[2].add_item(25);

    // for each group, print the member values
    for (int g = 0; g < setofgroups.size(); g++)
    {
        printf("group %d\n", g);
        for (int i = 0; i < setofgroups[g].count(); i++)
            printf("  member %d, value %d\n", i, setofgroups[g][i]);
    }

    // Group of groups doesn't seem to work

    Group<Group<int>> groupofgroups(numgroups);

    // this returns ZERO - not 3 as I expected
    printf("groupofgroups count=%d\n", groupofgroups.count());

    groupofgroups[0].add_item(6);
    groupofgroups[0].add_item(9);
    groupofgroups[0].add_item(15);
    groupofgroups[0].add_item(18);

    printf("groupofgroups[0].count=%d\n", groupofgroups[0].count()); // this returns ZERO - where did the items go?

    groupofgroups[1].add_item(7);

    // two items in third
    groupofgroups[2].add_item(8);
    groupofgroups[2].add_item(25);

    // for each group, print the member values
    for (int g = 0; g < groupofgroups.count(); g++)
    {
        printf("group 2  %d (count=%d)\n", g, groupofgroups[g].count());
        for (int i = 0; i < groupofgroups[g].count(); i++)
            printf("  member %d, value %d\n", i, groupofgroups[g][i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
       setofgroups count=3
    group 0
      member 0, value 6
      member 1, value 9
      member 2, value 15
      member 3, value 18
    group 1
      member 0, value 7
    group 2
      member 0, value 8
      member 1, value 25
    groupofgroups count=0

groupofgroups[0].count=0
```

Comment: In your Group constructor you set current_size to 0, and you only change it in add_item(), which you never call for the outer Group.

Comment: Two tips.  (1)  `operator T()` is normally better off returning a reference.    (2)   Look up "rule of three", "rule of five", "rule of zero".

Comment: `std::vector` uses _placement new_-operator so that `T` doesn't need to be default-constuctible and copyable when expanding. Consider using it if you want the same behaviour as `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things to fix:

- as suggested in the comment you need to set the current_size in the constructor
- you need to return a reference with you `operator[]` else all modification will be applied to a temporary copy of the element

[link to the code](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMeFsgYisAag6yAwgDdMyIsQ3YOABgCCchUpWZ1W5IIL5UR0xfMFMAWwAOzT3aaSkyCgqoAKq7mwaGqAOLEoj5uHADsfOaqqj7EeNpMniBuWVnhqgBU6AVMGhlmJaoKBKrIYsSYLAQA%2BoJ4AF6YtcUlTapeTAAePf2DsnXDOXkFksNZ2qh46KqYEz6s6BAAlEPmCyIARgx4yEWZJQlJRyf194kiPhCjvQPHc6uqAD8Hu8nn9TndStwAGyqVA%2BTDEAokDgAVj4KIAIp9Oo0WFgJocWqgWI5ng1RmgRJ0jkSSQQySMcUx0OguoRvBA0HSIqoWJgAO5szxeX7zVIY55uYV%2BZaBGJhSKyYzmYHJLSK7AgECqp6ndL/KoEJh2DGqAByAFUADJWhlZcZTb62DSmkx2lptDrdJ0m1RusEWcUpDzeGUBDRBZixDVuVURjVanVfGbHPV1ckAM1UEB9EdUXFTLwaWVzslNXHdhuNLt5AoiqJ4TtREoDDQd0wGvqbrZKrWI7U6HedZdU3bFEvBZml/mHkZCCqiZjj6qMWqBbw%2BhbS6ZGWYgVdUYDANctNsLxZKWAYmE8Debqir7r7A%2B9M19/p39smQ/fkqDk%2BnWUI3leslTcdZNniDd41XEAdj2PFdUDT9Gj3A8XRPa0rXPEpt3%2BBpny9H8aw/fCSnbUty3dBp0JHPl%2BXrNEK0xd00gnIttgYQRBghdR9V4hoAHpBIvRZOgzCBuC4eD9gUYB1C4FEJlUDNEi8BSUS2IgNPQVFNBYKTSFUAgEDwQQjMIwcnQsz0rJmcoC0lASSjKcppTMfsmAAT19ejGJ4Ci33KfNm2okoMxIbNRjwX85kaQIxm/MdGn4fgcIvPDnIvdzPK8hs8HvGtHzRAqWJ7DL/3cDiaMwa9bzRe9H3K4taNNHLETy5q2ySt8a0CztgorZq2JSSqpVDGc5SjBcwPMUZl00BMQGZVl2S8TliUcHl6KFbwt34jjhO2XZ9mMhBbCYXLUNrCRQkuvLeP5Uzr2zSzX07VwRwgfrMEOdLixkxDRWDQ6RJW3b1JM2w/JMuSDWqBs3qHQq6IFCGn1s97Bl4VLmvaAgxBYV7MaHYG9XY8bfEm4DptA5UzAUK4%2BXrLgYQWpa4QRJFDAazFsWaBR8UJLlSTTf58cJh8EZKvEdlCgMRoAiagPsWmYzmlgmdseboJXJUtUpalhc2%2Bkxd4iXiCJpGx1GimNeacYFCQzLQdUAA1PQDFhLNVTCfkSAAazCDMFB4qryRxFgRC8YANzCGtZFqVQjqoEQttkVRY6SYPIs8Rw4cnISwdUXR9Ei1Afbj/5HHQLVS4MCMFqaT7sFHG8K6z95BAgKOY7jsnw5KMSCAkqTuKIDNO58MJDfpMtuE0vSDK4LgjPHju44AOidI4B/%2BI7hC8Ww8%2BaR9eKOgAWRphTCBQVLwYgtqn6v28nqu0TdTFN/BtaIChAeGjrzftnBsn8MTfxZBDCAABOABJQgFT0EKA5sEDVrCggLQFEcCSyv0Qcgr%2BP90G0AABx73PiJYk2thS4jblyXSvEEHvx4LQFBhCOSpDIa7Ag/tr7eFvkTWGxB6EcUYSApirDIG/1Ie6URXcGzMXAWw9ailOFFxUpFTATBkAIEzhuIyw8zq2CPl4c4CIS5MGUJgJBvEIrECijieSJEk6OK0G3CeiDt4zFBDwTOqVeD/RdheLIw9R4rynjpJehlM7YOLLY%2BxAtYo%2BJinmWR08GzABQbPbxKUcb%2BLIqJXI4lJIr3tN4UxdiF7oCMvkSxESUT6SiXgNeuCmEZJYiVZsMTFaDyyEdVU3tdHZwfKgKxLAwBSGaNxbwxlUCqH9sQAOIMGgLSbp0Fugz3gb2zj3aOiDVElCOrDMIFsSSqAAFrYAAEoAHlVAAFpeSoGaBnEIqgACSx14T6EwMIhoITilcCnlsruRIqRzwlIpXS9Tl6rw2T4YF09N5ZL%2Bk5DiQLgFyI/hItBHJ/7unRXgrFBDJHoNgfijcCKkFEsUSSjkmCYkEqYWA1BUCSH7OCYUkeALGViJ4My2eGFIWRJXkZHlmK%2BWZNEEbUUycRJHNUCcsIFybn3LmeddoD5IJQ14V4MIwAXCyAAGJLJKGKtJaIWHEpxetDhqK1HcNmWtfhZ0H6/NNRSjF5qeAKJZVIhlHrCXeuxVAlRdqDkiTiZo7RcL9GcsMWMMpZiakiCsf8OJ/NM6JMzXmM1ggkVSoINkjJuSeABIOkE7InLQmAo3PmLIlTXoFsFZpY40KonAFFQG1pkqwW7zClkdN0Us3JNcbm9JPajZJwKiW/6Fb/lSVKSYsxlTqkWJTXUhpIrGidqSJS8d7SeClQxF0sa5sbyS1IuTKQhxGDSBRFIUgLBpAmAfagaQmg/E%2BOEGICQClZC0AfQQZ916b0BxABfLgm9aAXxMNA6BXBaBQlSLQEwJDZC3qkBfB9T6pAvtIG%2BqQD7BAgBMKQIDuHr2kDgLAJAaBfB4GvGQCgG16OMZAMAYh9AQ4ME8I/Sg5xgOkHOAoe60gAOkDo0fTo1zNZeUE1gcYbBrzyYfp7PIVjBM7D0CIQoUhxNNFqoJgguQvDAZvcwNgKBP2MDwOcYjkAb1wgIHgTa0g7k1xdJwEttBxPfvEJIWg5m73YcEwRiYxCoR3KhFfYAyBkCqGIVB7MuBCCRTkPQVQmhUCseXVwf9hIP0lsA2Z0DIAUSpE3sQlE0CTAmFSMQ2QXBiHQM46kDDWHH2hekERkjZGSsYa4CFij%2BHut9Yo39UguhH4uafRfIAA)

Comment: Fantastic! - thanks so much all of you.  With those changes, it works great.

Comment: Ummm it runs but it's not right. The design of this is that current_size indicates how many of the array items are valid i.e. you can init a Group initialized with size 10 but current_size indicates that none are valid.  If you add say 4 items, current size will be 4 and only [0]-[3] are valid.

Comment: When the space available runs out, the space is doubled. So - although setting current size to size in the constructor works here  it messes up in use elsewhere. Current size is the number of valid/set items, not the maximum space availanble.

Comment: @rapcoder when you have a size of 4 only elements from 0 to 3 included are valid this is perfectly normal. and if current_size is the number of element you test should check for max_size instead of current_size before setting values

Answer (score 0):

You have a non trivial destructor in you class. That means that the default copy constructor and default copy assignment will make the wrong thing.

Here is a simple example:

```
Group<int> a(4);  // ok, ready to add some elements in the freshly allocated a.data
a.add_item(1);
int count = a.add_item(2);   // ok a contains 2 items 1 and 2

if (count == 2) {
    Group<int> b = a;        // the default copy ctor make b.data == a.data...
    std::cout << "b contains " << b.count() << " items" << std::endl; // nice up to here
}             // horror: b reaches end of life and destructor calls delete[](b.data) !

// a.data is now a dangling pointer...
```

So you have to either implement the copy constructor and the copy assignment operator or mark them explicitely deleted - that is the rule of 3 (more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3279543/3545273))

If you do not implement them, the compiler will implicitely provide a move ctor and a move assignment operator that do not work much greater than the copy version. So you must implement them or mark them explicitely deleted - that is the rule of 5.

And the recommended `operator []` for containers - what standard library ones use - is:

```
T& operator[] (size_t index);              // used for  a[i] = ...
const T& operator[] (size_t index) const;  // used for  x = a[i];
```

Using references may avoid unnecessary copies of large objects...

Comment: The original code has other stuff but I removed it for this example (thinking the problem was elsewhere). I have:  Group(const Group<T>& copyfrom); // copy constructor 
 void operator = (const Group<T>& copyassign); // copy assign constructor

Comment: These are what I understand as copy and copy-assign (though I may be wrong of course).  If I add these in to this example, it still doesn't work.  Is there a way to post extra code, rather than inside these little comment boxes?

Comment: `template<class T> inline void Group<T>::operator= (const Group<T>& copyassign )
{
 int newSize = copyassign.count();
 if (max_size < newSize)
  {
  if (data != 0)
   delete[] data;
  data = new T[newSize];
  max_size = newSize;
  }
 T* caArray = copyassign.data;
 for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i++)
  {
  data[i] = caArray[i];
  }
 current_size = newSize;
}

`

Comment: `template<class T> Group<T>::Group(const Group<T>& copyfrom)
{
 data = 0;
 max_size = 0;
 current_size = 0;
 
 int newSize = copyfrom.count();

 if (max_size < newSize) 
  {
  if (data != 0)
   delete[] data;
  data = new T[newSize];
  max_size = newSize;
  }

 T* copyArray = copyfrom.data;
 for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i++) 
  {
  data[i] = copyArray[i];
  }
 current_size = newSize;
}
`